# Hide the title from UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

Is there any way to hide the title view in a UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The titleView is a UIView :

> titleView
>       A custom view displayed in the center of the navigation bar when this
>   item is the top item.
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *titleView
> ```

So I think you can try this :

```
[titleView setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: what is that a subview of though? `[nc.navigationItem.titleView setHidden:YES];` doesn't work...

Comment: And if you set it to nil like this nc.navigationItem.titleView = nil ?

Comment: When self.title is set to nil and you try to push it into stack, a back button will not appear. :(

Answer (score 15):

`self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.title = @"Home";`

Setting to nil will NOT work as described in documentation:
If this property value is nil, the navigation item’s title is displayed in the center of the navigation bar when the receiver is the top item. If you set this property to a custom title, it is displayed instead of the title.

Comment: There's no need for the `self.title = @"Home";` part I don't think.

Comment: it simply works. (self.title= @"home") is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

Another option which preserves the back button (as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23113326/1156575):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor clearColor]
}];
```

Comment: Note: the transparent title will still be readable by VoiceOver so you can't rely on this to hide the title for all users.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution in swift needed to be in my navigationbar subclass:

```
self.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clearColor()]
```

With the clear color the title disappears. As Josema described, you can also do this by accessing the navigationbar from your navigationcontroller:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clearColor()]
```

Comment: For Xcode 15, Swift 5 using the clear color still works: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
```