# hiding title of navigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

my first view named "back". I need to hidden the title of the navigationbar because I have my custom navigation bar.

I try with this code but it didn't work!

```
self.title = @"back";
self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 11):

Just faced the same issue, and doing:

```
self.title = @"YourTitle";
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Did the trick. The next view will have the back button labeled with *YourTitle* but in the first one, the title won't be shown.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to hide entire navigation bar and if you want to use your own navigation bar, you can first hide navigation controller's navigation bar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

or if you want to only hide title you can do

```
self.title = @"";
```

or if you have used custom title view for navigation bar, you can do

```
self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES;
```

or if you want to hide back bar button item, you can do

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
```

Comment: I need to hiding only the title

Comment: So use only `self.title = @""`

Comment: I used a custom navigation bar with image. I named the view with back, and I need to hiding only the title. I try your solution self.navigationItem.titleView.hidden = YES; but didn't work!

Comment: If I used self.title = @"" in the second view I haven't the back button of the navigationcontroller

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue, I just create a fake UIView to populate the titleView property and hide it :

```
UIView *fakeTitleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
fakeTitleView.hidden = YES;
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:fakeTitleView];
[fakeTitleView release];
```

Hope it could help.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which preserves the back button:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor clearColor]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift

```
self.navigationItem.title = "your title" // So title shows nav "back" button
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIView() // To hide the title on this View Controller
```

I put this in `viewWillAppear`